# About system properties

Tags: android, android-ndk, system-properties

I know how to access the Android system properties from the application layer.
In framework layer `android.os.SystemProperties` class take the responsibility  to 
get  all the properties. But internally  it calls some C code for getting 
the properties like `native_get(key,value)`.
Anyone please tell me which file is basically referred in the C code?

Answer (score 6):

Native code for that methods located in the file [`android_os_SystemProperties.cpp`](http://androidxref.com/4.1.1/xref/frameworks/base/core/jni/android_os_SystemProperties.cpp). It delegates them to the Bionic libc library [`/bionic/libc/bionic/system_properties.c`](http://androidxref.com/4.1.1/xref/bionic/libc/bionic/system_properties.c) which reads property value from the shared memory.

Here is the quote from the "[Android property system](http://rxwen.blogspot.com/2010/01/android-property-system.html)" article (I suggest you to read it all if you wish to understand how Android properties work):

> init process will load properties from following files:
>
> ```
> /default.prop  
> /system/build.prop
> /system/default.prop
> /data/local.prop
> ```
>
> The next step is start property service. In this step, a unix domain socket server is created. This socket's pathname is `"/dev/socket/property_service"` which is well known to other client processes.
>    Finally, init process calls poll to wait for connect event on the socket.
>
> On the consumer side, when it initializes libc (`bionic/libc/bionic/libc_common.c __libc_init_common function`). It will retrieve the fd and size from environment variable, and map the shared memory into its own space (`bionic/libc/bionic/system_properties.c __system_properties_init function`). After that, libcutils can read property just as normal memory for the consumer.

Answer (score 3):

These are not part of the SDK APIs.